# Encrypting files with php/mcrypt is corrupting docx (and other Microsoft Office 2007) files but others are fine

Tags: php, codeigniter, docx, mcrypt

I'm working with a CodeIgniter application to encrypt uploaded files then decrypt them when downloaded so they can be stored safely (alongside other security measures). This is all working fine, apart from docx (and other Microsoft Office 2007+) files. When these are downloaded they are successfully decrypted but Office detects them as corrupt. These can be repaired, so they're not totally corrupted, but something has changed in the file from the original version which is making Office see them as corrupt. As I mentioned, this doesn't seem to be happening to any other file types (that I have noticed). The docx files are also slightly different in size (only a matter of bytes), whereas other types are not.

To encrypt, I upload the file, read the contents into a string with file_get_contents(), then run the string through CodeIgniter's encode() in the encrypt library then save the file back to disk, deleting the original:

```
function mcrypt_encode($data, $key)
{
    $init_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->_get_cipher(), $this->_get_mode());
    $init_vect = mcrypt_create_iv($init_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    return $this->_add_cipher_noise($init_vect.mcrypt_encrypt($this->_get_cipher(), $key, $data, $this->_get_mode(), $init_vect), $key);
}
```

and to decode:

```
function mcrypt_decode($data, $key)
{
    $data = $this->_remove_cipher_noise($data, $key);
    $init_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->_get_cipher(), $this->_get_mode());

    if ($init_size > strlen($data))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $init_vect = substr($data, 0, $init_size);
    $data = substr($data, $init_size);
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt($this->_get_cipher(), $key, $data, $this->_get_mode(), $init_vect), "\0");
}
```

Then run the decoded string through CodeIgniter's [force_download()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html)

The default cipher is MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 and mode is MCRYPT_MODE_CBC. Mcrypt is enabled on my server along with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256.

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to why this might be happening it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with `file_get_contents` and binary data. http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42661

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The link provided suggests using readfile() as an alternative. How might I do this? Readfile seems to send the contents of the file to the output buffer rather than returning it as a string.

Comment: You wouldn't use `readfile` for the reason you mentioned. What you want is [`fread`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php). Note the warning in Example #2 regarding opening binary files in Windows (no idea what your platform is, but just in case...)

Comment: To expand/explain, files opened on windows without explicit 'binary' flag will have their line endings translated to \r\n.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but the problem is still occurring and it's still only docx (and Office 2007+) files. One thing I did notice is that it has only started happening since I have started using mcrypt. The application is running on a Linux server.

Any more ideas?

Comment: As a workaround I have managed to stop the docx from becoming corrupt by compressing it first with gzcompress() and then encrypting the compressed file. This also saves on space, which is a bonus :)

Answer (score 0):

[`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) the [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) of file, then encrypt.

[`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) the decrypted `file_get_contents()` of encrypted file before downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing almost the same thing and got here from google.

I solved it now. The problem is not in the `file_get_contents()`, the problem is the encode function in codeigniter. The function removes certain special characters thus removing data from the file. It's interesting how Microsoft office was able to repair it back.